# Finding N'th Fibonacci mod 2^m

Tags: fibonacci

(F(n) = N'th fibonacci number)
Compute the number X = F(n) mod 2^m  where (0 <= n <= 2 147 483 647) and (0 <= m < 20).

Hello this is the question, I was trying to solve it however the input values are so large that I cannot solve it less than 1 second. Could you please tell me an efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute after every summation the modulu. The result is the same.